# Binding events to functions within objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, signalr

I'm running into a peculiar issue with jQuery/JS in general.

I'm working on a JS file that let me create portlets for a client site. I'm using `SignalR` to communicate changes to the users.

The following piece of code gives me a bit of a headache as to why it won't work.

```
Eenheden: function (poPortlet) {
        this.moPortlet = poPortlet;
        this.Init = function () {
           $(this.moPortlet).find('.portlet-title').text($(this.moPortlet).attr('data-cpv-type') + ' Eenheden')
        };
        this.BindHub = function () {
           CPV.moHub.on('onEenheidUpdate', this.Events.Update);
        };
        this.Events = {
           Update: function (pnId, psStatus) {
              CPV.Log('Error', 'Update: ' + pnId + ' ' + psStatus);
           }
        };
     }
```

I am trying to bind the function `this.Events.Update` on the `SignalR` event `onEenheidUpdate`. Instances of these `Eenheiden` objects are not unique on the pages. The idea is that they contain the same data, but can get filtered, creating a different portlet depending on some configs.

My problem is that the `onEenheidUpdate` function doesn't trigger the proper event. I want to do it like this so I can use references I set for the unique object, such as the jQuery object I set on initialization.

Comment: have you ever invoke this bind function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Problem

Your problem is that when jQuery or javascript in general triggers an event callback, the "context" (value of `this`) is changed. For example

```
var MyModule = {
    init: function () {
        $('.amazing-element').on('click', function () {
            // This breaks because `
            // `this` is not MyModule
            // When the callback is triggered
            // `this` is `<p class="amazing-element"></p>`
            this.onClick()
        })
    },
    onClick: function () {
        console.log('wee, I was clicked')
    }
}
```

## [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) to the rescue!

```
var MyModule = {
    init: function () {
        $('.amazing-element').on('click', function () {
            this.onClick()
        }.bind(this))
        // ^ here we bind the context of the callback to the
        // correct version of `this`.
    },
    onClick: function () {
        console.log('wee, I was clicked')
    }
}
```

So your exact example would look like:

```
Eenheden: function (poPortlet) {
    this.moPortlet = poPortlet;
    this.Init = function () {
       $(this.moPortlet).find('.portlet-title').text($(this.moPortlet).attr('data-cpv-type') + ' Eenheden')
    };
    this.BindHub = function () {
       CPV.moHub.on('onEenheidUpdate', this.Events.Update.bind(this));
                                                      // ^ change here
    };
    this.Events = {
       Update: function (pnId, psStatus) {
          CPV.Log('Error', 'Update: ' + pnId + ' ' + psStatus);
       }
    };
 }
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your time. I've tried to use your suggestion, and that helps with maintaining the reference to the object. I now have the issue that the event won't fire unless I bind the same event somewhere else. If I place `CPV.moHub.on('onEenheidUpdate', function (pnId, psStatus) {});` somewhere in the script, like in the init of the JS file, it will properly trigger the suggestion you did.

Comment: I'm not sure which framework you're using, and that problem is outside the scope of this question besides